# Use lines in a file to produce string and file name

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, files

I have a file, `foo.txt`, that has a folder name on each line:

```
folder_1
folder_2
folder_3
```

And I'd like to do something like this:

```
cat foo.txt | xargs -I {} echo 'function {}() { return stuff; }' > {}/function.js
```

In other words, I'd like to read a file line by line, then use each line to both create a string and create the name of the file in which the string is stored.

How does one do something like this from the command line in bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just loop over all lines in the file:

```
while read line
do
    echo "function $line() { return stuff; }" > "$line/function.js"
done < foo.txt
```

Of course this assumes you have already directories named as lines in the `foo.txt`. If this is not the case then first create them with `mkdir "$line"`.

---

Another approach, with `awk` instead of loop would be:

```
awk '{printf("%s\n","function "$0"() { return stuff; }")>$0"/function.js"}' foo.txt
```

Comment: Thank you! I am trying to do this entirely from the command line, though. Because... super powers, ya know? :D

Comment: @Nope well..., this **is** command line solution. You can even make it one-liner if that's needed by removing all newlines and adding semicolon (`;`) in front of `do` and `done`.

Comment: Shyuh, as soon as I wrote that, I thought, "Wait a minute. H e wasn't saying write this in a file."

Comment: I am too noob to upvote. So--here, have a virtual upvote.

Comment: @Nope See the update of my answer - I've added `awk` solution, perhaps more compact.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! The loop sure is more readable, yeah? I can't remember how many times I've tried something with sed awk--and then ended up switching to perl.

Comment: Why `awk`? `sed 's|.*|function &() { return stuff; } > &/function.js|' foo.txt`

Comment: @Costas - but that doesn't do anything but write to stdout - you'd need at least two seds for that to work - or to pipe it into a shell or something. But then you'd have to be absolutely certain of all of the quoting. We can take it for granted that the directory name is safe - it's a shell word or it couldn't be the name of a function, but all of the rest...? It's hard for me to believe that `return stuff` is a real world example.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `xargs` + `sh -c`:

```sh
<file1.txt xargs -d'\n' -L1 sh -c 'mkdir -p -- "$0"
printf %s\\n "function $0() { return stuff; }" >"$0"/function.js'
```

not using the `-I {}` construct to avoid expansion if your text file contains funky stuff (e.g. lines like `- $'\n' \ $PATH`).